# How Much Gig Needed For Installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Newbie here.  How much space does Ubuntu need to install.  I thought it was 50 Gig.  But, it requested half my drive 449 Gig (half a terabyte).  Installing 16.0.4

How many Gig for Ubuntu itself?

Comment: If you have Windows installed as well, Ubuntu will take half the drive space for dual boot. Ubuntu only needs around 6GB to install, but I recommend you give it at least 40.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought from the docs 50 Gig was sufficient for the system and whatever s/w & data I would install.

Comment: I see the bootable USB stick has just 1.5 Gig on it.

Comment: The installation files on the USB stick are all compressed. Decompressed, they take around 6GB of space. Since you're probably planning on installing software and updates, you'll want room for that.

Answer (score 1):

At Canonical's website, they recommend at least 25GB, but it all depends of your intended usage. For general usage, 50GB is more than enough.